# Error thrown in tomcat console on refresh on close of browser in tomcat for websocket connection

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, angular5

I am a application where I want to maintain a heartbeat to check if my browser is connected.
So for this i implemented a web socket.
I am using java in back-end and angular 5 in front end.

My code snippet java

```
    @ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint", configurator = HttpSessionConfigurator.class)
    public class WebServer {
      @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
    log.debug("on open session: "+ session.getId());
    this.httpSession = (HttpSession) config.getUserProperties().get(IBClientConstants.HTTP_SESSION);
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session session) { 
    log.debug("onClose session: "+ session.getId());
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    String data = "success";//i send some data which is needed in UI
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(data);
  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
    log.debug(t.getMessage());
  }
    }
```

My Angular side code:

```
@Injectable()
export class WebSocketClient {
    private webSocket;

    private websocketUrl;

    constructor(private appConfig: AppConfig) {
        this.websocketUrl = appConfig.getBaseURLWithContextPath();
        if (this.websocketUrl) {
            this.websocketUrl = this.websocketUrl.replace("http", "ws") + "/endpoint"
        }
        this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.websocketUrl);      
    }

    connect() {
        try {
            this.webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
                console.log('onopen::' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
            }
            this.webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
                var response = event.data;
                let jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
                //i use this data
            }
            this.webSocket.onclose = (event) => {
                console.log('onclose::' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
            }
            this.webSocket.onerror = (event) => {
                console.log('onerror::' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
            }

        } catch (exception) {
            console.error(exception);
        }
    }

    getStatus() {
        return this.webSocket.readyState;
    }

    ping() {
        if (this.webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
            this.webSocket.send("ping");

        } else {
            console.error('webSocket is not open. readyState=' + this.webSocket.readyState);
        }
    }
    disconnect() {
        console.log("disconnect");
        if (this.webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
            this.webSocket.close();

        } else {
            console.error('webSocket is not open. readyState=' + this.webSocket.readyState);
        }
    }

}
```

all the functionalities are working fine. But When I use https connection, that means my websocket url becomes wss://localhost:8443/InBetween/endpoint.
At this point in case i do a browser refresh in chrome , it is throwing exception in console.
below is the exception.:

```
 Aug 13, 2018 12:11:07 PM
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer doClose
 INFO: Failed to close the ServletOutputStream connection cleanly
 java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
 software in your host machine
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
         at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
         at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:135)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.close(SecureNioChannel.java:370)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.close(SecureNioChannel.java:398)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doClose(NioServletOutputStream.java:137)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.close(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:100)
         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doClose(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:138)
         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.close(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:597)
         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:113)
```

I tried calling disconnect() on browser refresh on close. But it did not help.
I test the same in IE, it is not giving any error.

My https connector:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="8443" maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="some path" keystorePass="password"/>
```

Comment: Please use code format for error messages and stack traces.  Much easier to read.  I fixed it this time.

Comment: ok.thank you. Any help on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because the web socket was not getting disconnected properly. 
I removed `this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.websocketUrl);`   from constructor and added a separate function to connect and used it where it is needed to connect to web socket. Also called disconnect function on browser refresh and close.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is useless, I just turn it off.

For turning off log to `tomcat8-stderr.2021-07-08.log`, change the log level to warning for console log in `/conf/logging.properties`

> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING

For turning off log to `catalina.2021-07-08.log`, add a line to `/conf/logging.properties`

> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.level =
> WARNING

Comment: Per this comment https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59062#c1 this appears to be the recommended approach. Thanks.